# Proguard rules - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to fix a proguard rules, but until now without success.
My project uses 5 libs with packages that start equal (com.mylibs.one, com.mylibs.two, ...)
I don't know if this was the problem, but when I write the rule in `proguard-rules.pro` I just specify one time `com.libs` .

When I run my app I got just `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

My proguard-rules.pro

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontshrink
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*


-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep class com.j256.**
-keep public class android.database.sqlite.**

-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }

-keep class com.samsung.** {*;}
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }

-keep class com.mylibs.** { *; }
-keep interface com.mylibs.** { *; }
-keep enum com.mylibs.** { *; }

-keep class com.mopub.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.zxing.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.** {*;}

-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void get*(...);
   public void set*(...);
   public void on*(...);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class com.mylibs {
    public *;
}

-dontwarn com.samsung.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontwarn com.mylibs.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn org.webrtc.**
-dontwarn com.google.zxing.**

-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.apache.**

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

Error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: com.myproject, PID: 10213
                                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lw;
                                                                  at com.mylibs.blabla.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.mylibs.blabla.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.mylibs.blabla.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.myproject.bla.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.myproject.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.myproject.application.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "w" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myproject-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myproject-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.myproject-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                  at com.mylibs.Config.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at com.mylibs.Config.build(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at com.mylibs.Config.build(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at com.myproject.Manager.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at com.myproject.Manager.build(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at com.myproject.Application.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: w
                                                                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                        ... 17 more
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Thx for help!

Comment: what is at com.myproject.application.onCreate() method?

Comment: There are some trackers init (facebook, analytics, twitter) and multidex install

Comment: @fe_araujo_ have you find any solution of your question?I have same issue

Comment: In my case was a conflict in the proguard rules in a third party library.